# What is wrong with my proof of variance of normal distribution?

Tags: statistics, definite-integrals, normal-distribution

Following is my proof for variance of a normal distribution. I got zero marks for this. Where am I wrong? 
[image: Pic of my proof]

Comment: Ask your grader / instructor why you received zero marks, not us.

Comment: In asking a Question (as in providing Answers) you should  avoid making the presentation as a simple link to content elsewhere.  Use the body of a Question to give a full statement of a problem you want help with, and have a look at the [introduction to posting mathematical expressions](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to lessen your need for images.

Comment: BTW Why are we taking derivative wrt to $\sigma$ ?